# Send data from Android studio to php

Tags: php, android

I know this subject has been approached several times. But it always uses Apache, that has been deprecated.
I want to send data from my App to my database. I know my PHP code works. But when I click on "Send" in my app, either it crashes the app or it works but doesn't send data to my database (or I just can't see it).

This is how I call my class "AddDataAsyncTask":

```
    btnnexttrip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick (View view) {
            Intent myIntent =new Intent(getBaseContext(), trip.class);
            AddData =new AddDataAsyncTask();
            AddData.execute();

            startActivityForResult(myIntent,0);
        }
    });
```

My class AddDataAsyncTask:

```
    private class AddDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.i("add", "onPreExecute");
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //I Use HashMap, it works similar to NameValuePair
        Map<String,String> dataToSend = new HashMap<>();
        dataToSend.put("id",hisid);
        dataToSend.put("name", hisname);
        dataToSend.put("age", hisage);
        dataToSend.put("job", hisjob);
        dataToSend.put("gender", hisgender);
        dataToSend.put("date_trip", hisdate);
        dataToSend.put("mode_trip", hismode);
        dataToSend.put("time_trip", histime);
        dataToSend.put("crowded_trip", hiscrowded);
        dataToSend.put("from_trip", hisfrom);
        dataToSend.put("to_trip", histo);
        dataToSend.put("majo_gender",hismajogender);
        dataToSend.put("majo_origin",hismajoorigin);

        String encodedStr = getEncodedData(dataToSend);

        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlAdd);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
            writer.write(encodedStr);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        Log.i("add", "onPostExecute");
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(success==1)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Good "+message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error " +message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to be "getEncodedData" in "doInBackground" that doesn't work:

```
    private String getEncodedData(Map<String,String> data) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(String key : data.keySet()) {
        String value = null;
        try {
            value = URLEncoder.encode(data.get(key),"UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(sb.length()>0){
            sb.append("&");
        }
        sb.append(key + "=" + value);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

I have the internet permission... This is the LogCat:

```
05-25 10:59:00.675 2468-3214/com.example.jeremydiez.sharedlifetracks E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                                                                                   Process: com.example.jeremydiez.sharedlifetracks, PID: 2468
                                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:325)
                                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
                                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
                                                                                       at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:205)
                                                                                       at com.example.jeremydiez.sharedlifetracks.tripsecondpart.getEncodedData(tripsecondpart.java:198)
                                                                                       at com.example.jeremydiez.sharedlifetracks.tripsecondpart.access$300(tripsecondpart.java:41)
                                                                                       at com.example.jeremydiez.sharedlifetracks.tripsecondpart$AddDataAsyncTask.doInBackground(tripsecondpart.java:268)
                                                                                       at com.example.jeremydiez.sharedlifetracks.tripsecondpart$AddDataAsyncTask.doInBackground(tripsecondpart.java:240)
                                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
                                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
                                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
                                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
                                                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

I tried to fix it (with the logcat) so I changed the "getEncodedData" to this:

```
    private String getEncodedData(Map<String,String> data) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : data.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        String value = entry.getValue();
        String encodedvalue = null;
        try {
            encodedvalue = URLEncoder.encode(key,"UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(sb.length()>0){
            sb.append("&");
        }
        sb.append(key + "=" + encodedvalue);
    }      
    return sb.toString();
}
```

With this one it didn't crash but didn't send anything to my database :/

Can someone help me please?

EDIT: That's how I defined my urlAdd:

```
    String urlAdd="http://192.168.15.32/enis_android_club/add_dbadd.php";
```

Is it the good way to do it?

Comment: e.printStackTrace doesnt work in Android, so if you dont use functional tests better replace it to Log.e("Tag",Log.getStackTraseString(e)); that will help to get Exception inside doInBackground

Comment: Thank you, I changed it, still the same problems :/

Answer (score 0):

try this, it works for me
first create a json parser class, like this :

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                  List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if (method == "POST") {
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } else if (method == "GET") {
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }


    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

}

And in your doInBackground method put this code :

```
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {


        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(("id",hisid)));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", hisname)); // put your values like this
        Log.e("params", params.toString());

        // getting JSON Object
                            final JSONObject jsonValid = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                                    urlAdd, "POST", params);

                            int successValid = jsonValid.getInt("success");

                            if (successValid == 1) {
                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                });
                            } else {
                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error",
                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            }
```

I have not organized this code well, try to organize it :)

Comment: Thank you but as I said, Apache has been deprecated so I can't make a NameValuePair List for example :/